# SQL Server Crashes Instantly

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I have SSMS 2016 installed on my server, but no database. There's an issue with SSMS on my user account on the server, not all accounts. Everytime I launch the app, it instantly crashes. I tried deleting the AppData folder, I tried deleting the registries, but neither fixed the issue. What can I do to fix the issue?

I found the following 3 errors happening every time in the Event Viewer:

1. .NET Runtime

> Application: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowSession.ConfigureEnvironment(System.Activities.Activity, Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.IWorkflowConfiguration, 
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ConfigureSession(Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionResumptionContext)
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.GotResumptionContextForProcessWaiter(System.IAsyncResult)
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ProcessMatch(Boolean)
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.StartEpisode()
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ReceiveNextMessage()
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ProcessNonTransactionalWork()
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion, System.IAsyncResult)
>
> at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
>
> Exception Info: System.AggregateException
>
> Exception Info: Microsoft.Workflow.Common.FatalException
>
> at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Fx+<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

2. Application Error:

> Faulting application name: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe, version: 1.0.20922.0, time stamp: 0x505e1b24
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18340, time stamp: 0x57366075
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000008a5c
>
> Faulting process id: 0x3cc8
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b130f82ae31e
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts\Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: 3e02c5e5-1d24-11e7-8115-00155d644266
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

3. Service Control Manager:

> The Workflow Manager Backend service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 77 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 30000 milliseconds: Restart the service.

Comment: your best bet would be to do all windows updates and update to latest version of sqlserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted my entire user profile from the server and it worked again. Still no idea what caused the issue though.

Comment: how to delete entire user profile? I facing ssms crash problems too